# Select top n columns based on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, filtering

I have a database as the following:

[image]

And I would like to obtain a pandas dataframe filtered for the 2 rows per date, based on the top  ones that have the highest population. The output should look like this:

[image]

I know that pandas offers a formula called nlargest:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html

but I don't think it is usable for this use case. Is there any workaround?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can `sort_values` (by `['Date', 'Population']`) and use `groupby` (by `'Date'`) ?

Comment: Its better to paste the data as part of post not the image. it helps people to test on your data and put the right answer. It is bad practice anytime to put the code or data as image

Comment: @iraciv94 , if you like the answer then you also upvote it ✔

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have mimicked your dataframe as below and provided a way forward to get the desired result.

### Your Dataframe:

```
>>> df
        Date country  population
0 2019-12-31       A         100
1 2019-12-31       B          10
2 2019-12-31       C        1000
3 2020-01-01       A         200
4 2020-01-01       B          20
5 2020-01-01       C        3500
6 2020-01-01       D          12
7 2020-02-01       D        2000
8 2020-02-01       E          54
```

### Your Desired Solution:

You can use `nlargest` method along with `set_index` ans `groupby` method.

This is what you will get..

```
>>> df.set_index('country').groupby('Date')['population'].nlargest(2)
Date        country
2019-12-31  C          1000
            A           100
2020-01-01  C          3500
            A           200
2020-02-01  D          2000
            E            54
Name: population, dtype: int64
```

Now, as you want the DataFrame into original state by resetting the index of the DataFrame, which will give you following ..

```
>>> df.set_index('country').groupby('Date')['population'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
        Date country  population
0 2019-12-31       C        1000
1 2019-12-31       A         100
2 2020-01-01       C        3500
3 2020-01-01       A         200
4 2020-02-01       D        2000
5 2020-02-01       E          54
```

### Another way around:

With `groupby` and `apply` function use `reset_index` with parameter `drop=True` and `level=` ..

```
>>> df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda p: p.nlargest(2, columns='population')).reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)
  # df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda p: p.nlargest(2, columns='population')).reset_index(level=['Date',1], drop=True)
        Date country  population
0 2019-12-31       C        1000
1 2019-12-31       A         100
2 2020-01-01       C        3500
3 2020-01-01       A         200
4 2020-02-01       D        2000
5 2020-02-01       E          54
```